# Select the baseline methods for ensemble time-series model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, ensemble-learning

I have been reading about ensemble time series models which have often been shown to perform better than single methods. I did not manage to find any reference on how to select the baseline methods. Should I use more forecasting methods to combine (the more the better) and any basic method (ARIMA, theta, naive) will do or is there some principled way of selecting those methods (e.g. having predictions which are negatively correlated or better uncorrelated)?

Comment: Have you found an answer? Surprised your question didn't receive more attention.

Comment: No answer unfortunately.

Comment: I'm facing exactly this same Q and about to embark on a series of experiments to convince myself how well time series ensemble work.

Comment: Please let us all know if you get something interesting!

Comment: If you have to pick some benchmark (publicly available) time series datasets, what would you choose?

Comment: From what I know the standard benchmark (which is a bit old now) is the M3 competition https://forecasters.org/resources/time-series-data/m3-competition/

Comment: Yea, aware of that. Headache for me is M1/M3 together are really over 1000 datasets. Don't want to wait hours/days run all models on all of them. Thanks for the suggestion.